# Given $A\in \mathcal M_{k\times l}(\Bbb F)$, prove that matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix} \ I_k & A \\ A^T & -I_l \end{pmatrix}$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

> Given $A\in \mathcal M_{k\times l}(\Bbb F)$, prove that the following matrix $$M=\begin{pmatrix}
> \ I_k & A \\
> A^T & -I_l
> \end{pmatrix}$$ is invertible.

---

I have tried to find its determinant and its rank, but it was not helpful in figuring it out. Could someone enlighten me on how I can find out whether the matrix is invertible?

Comment: Some assumption about $A$?

Comment: No assumption was given on A directly.

Comment: @JohnNam Considering the two answers below, it would be good that you precise in which field or type of fields $\mathbb F$ you're working.

Comment: I see, the question didn't specify the field of the matrix. I now understand that the real field is the correct field to yield the desired proof.

Comment: I think it does become correct again if we replace $A^T$ with $A^*$ (conjugate transpose) for the complex case.

Comment: if it were me I'd consider $D = \begin{pmatrix}
\ I_k & 0 \\ 0  & -I_l
\end{pmatrix}$  and $DM = S + I$  for skew symmetric $S$.  The problem reduces to the result that skew symmetric matrices have purely imaginary eigenvalues hence $\det\big(S+I\big)\neq 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $A,B,C,D$ matrices of appropriate sizes, you have [the formulae](http://djalil.chafai.net/blog/2012/10/14/determinant-of-block-matrices/)

$$\det(M)= \det(A-BD^{-1}C)\det(D)$$ where

$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Which gives in your particular case that

$$\det(M) = \det(I_k+A^TA)\det(-I_l).$$

We're left to prove that $\det(I_k+A^TA) \neq 0$, i.e. that $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A^TA$. And indeed if that was the case, we would be able to find $X \neq 0$ such that

$$\Vert AX \Vert^2 = X^T A^T A X = -X^TX = -\Vert X \Vert^2$$ and that can't be as the left side of the equality is non negative while the right side is strictly negative.

*Note: following the answer of "levap", I made here the assumption that $\mathbb F$ is $\mathbb R$ or a [formally real field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formally_real_field).*

Comment: Also eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are non-negative by the singular value decomposition.

Comment: @mathreadler You're right. Here we only need *a very small part* of the spectrum theorem.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: +1 for not using "anything" about positive semi-definite matrices. I'm leaving my answer because it doesn't use the block determinant formula which is not that well-known.

Answer (score 1):

The result is false as stated. For example, we can take $A = (i) \in M_{1 \times 1}(\mathbb{C})$ and then

$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \\ i & -1 \end{pmatrix} $$

with

$$ \det(M) = -1 - i^2 = 0. $$

However, note that we have

$$ M^2 = \begin{pmatrix} I & A \\ A^T & -I \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} I & A \\ A^T & -I \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} I + AA^T & 0 \\ 0 & I + A^T A \end{pmatrix} $$

and so

$$ \det(M^2) = \det(M)^2 = \det(I - AA^T) \det (I - A^T A). $$

If $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$, the matrices $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ are positive semi-definite and so have only non-negative eigenvalues. Hence, $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $AA^T,A^TA$ and so $I - AA^T,I - A^TA$ are invertible and so is $M$.

Comment: It's probably meant conjugate transpose in complex case?

Comment: @mathreadler: It's possible (and then the statement is true both over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ but doesn't make sense over other fields) but we won't know unless the OP gives us this information...