# How to use Gershgorin disc theorem to determine location of eigenvalues of $M = \begin{bmatrix}I_k&A\\A^T&-I_l\end{bmatrix}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, gershgorin-sets

There was a quite fast answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3708438/given-a-in-mathcal-m-k-times-l-bbb-f-prove-that-the-following-matrix-m)  regarding invertibility of $M$, but as I discovered more properties, I thought we must be able to find stronger results.

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}I_k&A\\A^T&-I_l\end{bmatrix}$$

**Experimental observations**

Based on numerical experiments with random matrices $A$ I think this shall be possible to prove that we will have $|k-l|$ eigenvalues at $1$ if $k>l$ and at $-1$ if $l>k$ and the rest in pairs $(1-t, 1+t)$ where $t>0$.

And that corresponding eigenvector pairs are orthogonal to one another.

---

**Own theoretical observations**

Now by Gershgorins circle theorem the eigenvalues are in circles with the radii the sum absolute values of A rows / columns, but midpoint different ($k$ have $+1$ and $l$ have $-1$).

By the spectral theorem since $M$ is symmetric also all eigenvalues will be along the real line.

But since $A$ can be any matrix, I cannot bound the radii, and it was too long ago when I last saw techniques used to bound these radii. I have some weak memory mentioning techniques using continuity to get better Gershgorin estimates. But I don't remember how to do it. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: suppose $k \gt l$, then your statement *"I think this shall be possible to prove that we will have $|k-l|$ eigenvalues at $1$ and the rest in pairs $(1-t, 1+t)$ where $t>0$*" is impossible because $\text{trace}(M) = k -l$ and M isn't the identity matrix

Comment: @user8675309 I don't understand your remark but for $l>k$ then there will be $l-k$ $\lambda=-1$s and not $1$s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential case is this one

$\textbf{Proposition.}$ Assume that $k<l$ and that $A$ has full rank $k$. Let $(\sigma_i)_{i\leq k}$ be the $k$ positive singular values of $A$. Then

$spectrum(M)=\{\pm\sqrt{1+\sigma_i^2};i=1,\dots,k\}\cup \{-1,\cdots,-1; l-k\;\times\}$.

$\textbf{Proof.}$ Note that $AA^T$ is invertible and $spectrum(AA^T)=(\sigma_i^2)_i$. 
If $\lambda\not= -1$, then

$\det(M-\lambda I_{k+l})=\det((1-\lambda)I_k-A(-1-\lambda)^{-1}A^T)\det((-1-\lambda)I_l)=0$

IFF $\det((1-\lambda^2)I_k+AA^T)=0$.

Thus $\lambda$ is in the form $\pm\sqrt{1+\sigma_i^2}\notin[-1,1]$. These are the $2k$ eigenvalues ​​of $M$ (with multiplicity) which are $\not= -1$. Clearly, the $l-k$ remaining eigenvalues are equal to $-1$. In particular, we can verify that $tr(M)=-(l-k)$.  $\square$

Comment: I am still curious about Gershgorin solution, but this is great also. Thank you !